# Is it possible to import a whole project from Azure Devops into MS-project?

Tags: azure-devops, ms-project

As the title implies: is it possible to import a whole project from Azure Devops (TFS) into MS-project?

I am missing the "Team" tab in ms-project.

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below steps could help you view the Teams tab? Feel free to leave comment if you still have puzzle about it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to import a whole project from Azure Devops (TFS) into
>   MS-project?

Of course yes. In fact, call it import is not accurate. It's work logic is connect the MS project with TFS, then **get\access** the whole WIT from the TFS project.

As you said, you haven't seen the "Team" tab in MS project, firstly, you should ensure that the Visual Studio version you installed does match [**2010 or later**](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs). If the version match and still could not see the tab Team, you should follow the below steps to install the [Team Foundation Server Standalone Office Integration](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?q=Office%20Integration).

- Go **File** menu, choose **Options**.
- Choose **Add-ins** and from the **Manage** picklist, choose **COM
  Add-ins**, and then choose **Go**.

[image]

- Ensure that the **Team Foundation Add-in** checkbox has checked.

Due to this official doc for more detailed steps: [Enable the Team Foundation Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/tfs-office-integration-issues?view=tfs-2017#enable-the-team-foundation-add-in).